# How to get the invoking_key of complete function with readline?

Tags: python, autocomplete, readline

I'm new in coding, and have been working on a cisco os style command line interface with auto-completion function. It seems python's builtin module readline would be my feasible choice.
I intend to make the key-presses of 'TAB', 'space' and '?' to achieve completion with slight different behaviors, but only one complete function is supported to be bound to, and i'm not sure if there is a way to get which key has just invoked this function. Or should i look for other choice for this purpose?
Any hint will be much appreciated!

Comment: Into what environment are you trying to add auto complete?  Python interactive shell?  Editor?  Actual system shell?  Most of these have auto complete already.

Comment: i'm trying to build my own command line interface on a linux server(with python 2.x), which can auto-complete pre-designed data-based parameters just like a cisco switch/router. e.g.  Rt# config (press-enter)   Rt>config# interface (press-enter)   Rt>config>interface# para1 para2 ... @DanFarrell

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autocomplete/0.0.104

Comment: i'll study on this, thanks in advance @DanFarrell

Comment: unluckily it's not what i'm looking for :-(

Answer (score 0):

Based on readline 6.2.4.1, I added a new function to pass the value of variable rl_completion_invoking_key to python in readline.c, and generated my own readline.so. Then I can decide different behaviors according to the invoking keys in the complete() function.

```
readline.c:
static PyObject *
get_completion_invoking_key(PyObject *self, PyObject *noarg)
{
    return PyInt_FromLong(rl_completion_invoking_key);
}

PyDoc_STRVAR(doc_get_completion_invoking_key,
"get_completion_invoking_key() -> int\n\
Get the invoking key of completion being attempted.");

static struct PyMethodDef readline_methods[] =
{
...
{"get_completion_invoking_key", get_completion_invoking_key,
METH_NOARGS, doc_get_completion_invoking_key},
...
}

in my own code:
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")    # invoking_key = 9
readline.parse_and_bind("space: complete")  # invoking_key = 32
readline.parse_and_bind("?: complete")      # invoking_key = 63

def complete(self, text, state):
    invoking_key = readline.get_completion_invoking_key()
```